# Zend_Db_Select Select values not in specific table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I've googled my question and read through a bunch of forum posts but I've yet to find the answer I'm looking for hopefully someone here can help me out.

For a project I'm building I've set up the following 3 tables; users, projects and projectUsers.

I've set up a form where I can add users to projects by saving the userID and the projectID in the projectUsers table nothing special so far. The form contains a select element with userIDs that can be connected to a projectID (hidden field).

This form element is filled with a query set up with Zend_Db_Select it selects all the users from the users table and adds it to the select. However I want to filter that result so it excludes all of the users already added to that specific project.

Short version: I have a select element with users filled with a resultset from a (Zend_db_select) database query I want that resultset to be stripped from certain userIDs.

For extra reference the table scheme below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `projectID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projectName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`projectID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projectUsers` (
  `projectUserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projectID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`projectUserID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userFirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userLastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addint to  Soica Micea ans

```
$blackList = array(1,3,5,6); //user id which you want to exclude
$db->select()->from('users', '*')
    ->joinLeft('projectUsers', 'projectUsers.projectUserID = users.userID', null)
    ->where('projectUsers.projectID = ?', someProjectID)
    ->where('projectUserID is null')
    ->where('users.userID not in (?)', implode(',',$blackList))
    ->query()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select all users that have not been added to a project and ignore users from arrayOfUserIds

```
select()->from('users', '*')
    ->joinLeft('projectUsers', 'projectUsers.projectUserID = users.userID', null)
    ->where('projectUsers.projectID = ?', someProjectID)
    ->where('projectUserID is null')
    ->where('users.userID not in (?)', arrayOfUserIds)
    ->query()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Does the array of userIds need to be a one dimensional array like:
    array(1,3,12)